# Open Elfinder 2.X from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my CMS I used Elfinder 1.X, which was integrated into CKEditor and I could open an other instance by clicking an input as well. Now I updated Elfinder to 2.0 and the input doesn't want to work anymore.

Here's the code I had:

```
function load_elfinder($id) {
$('<div />').elfinder({
url : 'lib/modules/elfinder/connectors/php/connector.php',
lang : 'hu',
dialog : { width : 900, modal : false },
editorCallback : function(url) {
document.getElementById($id).value = url;
}
})
}
```

And then:
    $(".news_index").on('click',function(){
    load_elfinder('news_index');
    });

Now this function doesn't work. With CKEditor it works perfectly. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You need to change connector codes too. Use `getFileCallback` instead of `editorCallback`. It's changed from version 1.0, but the wiki is not updated well.